# Can I go to Mexico with a J-1 visa right before it expires?

Tags: usa, mexico, j1-visas, thai-citizens

I have a US J-1 visa that will expire on July 20th. I want to go to Mexico before I go back to my country on July 17th for 3 weeks. Will I be able to enter Mexico?

Comment: Will your J-1 program be finished when you go to Mexico?  If it will be, when will it have ended?  Will you re-enter the US from Mexico before returning to Thailand?

Comment: I'm finished 20 july and I don't re-enter the US. I returning to thailand from mexico - Turkey - Thailand

Comment: So, to be clear, the question you are asking is, will Mexican immigration allow you to enter without a Mexican visa based on your valid, but soon-to-expire, US visa?

Comment: yes, like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

If your Thai passport and the US J-1 visa in your passport both remain valid at the time you travel to Mexico, you will be able enter Mexico for tourism and vacation, then fly back to Thailand without reentering the US.

Source: [IATA Travel Centre](https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/).